# Creating an Account with dummy authenticator

Tags: android

I am trying to create an account in Accounts & Sync which doesn't require authentication. I have already referred to [SampleSync](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/src/com/example/android/samplesync/index.html) example. The key difference between the example and what I am trying to build is Authentication. I don't want to display an Authentication/Login activity to the user. Is it possible to create an account directly from Authenticator service without having an Authentication activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`AccountAuthenticatorActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountAuthenticatorActivity.html) activity is completely optional. If the [Authenticator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AbstractAccountAuthenticator.html) can authenticate without it (like in the case of anonymous access) there is no need for any activities to be available. Your [SyncAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.html) can even be coded not to get any account info, as there isn't any needed.

In your Authenticator you may however make it impossible to create more than one account, just for clarity sake.

Comment: It's really an assumption. Besides, I need something similar to News/Stocks/Weather accounts present in HTC devices. They sync without asking user of account info. Hence, skipping a step in the workflow.

Comment: Would be nice if there was a concrete implementation of syncadapter without any account management. Something to start off with.